# Godot - Simple spartial shader results too bright (unshaded, custom)

Tags: godot, godot-shader-language

:)

**TL:DR**

When writing a **custom spatial shader** the `ALBEDO` color isn't the output color, even if `render_mode unshaded` is set.

---

**Long story**

I created a new project in Godot v3.4.4.stable.official [419e713a2] and simply added two CSGBox.

For the **left one** I assigned a **SpatialMaterial** and set it to **unshaded** and assigned an **albedo texture** (see below). The result is as expected.

However, for the **right one** I assigned a **ShaderMaterial** and wrote the following, very simple, shader:

```
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;

uniform sampler2D albedo;

void fragment() {
  ALBEDO = texture(albedo, UV).rgb;
}
```

After assigning the **same texture** to the `albedo` shader parameter, the result is a lot too bright. I already tried several render_modes, variables such as SPECULAR and other things like texture import settings, but couldn't figure out how to get the same result as the left box.

**The texture**

[image: The texture I choose]

**The result**

[image: The two cubes]

Left side: As expected using SpatialMaterial, Right side: Too bright using ShaderMaterial

**Sample project**

Well, it's nothing big, but if you want to take a look: https://files.catbox.moe/nj407g.zip

**Thank you in advance ❤**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that is often dismissed in tutorials and explanations: Adding `hint_albedo` tells Godot to do an sRGB to linear conversion. The documentation about [uniforms](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/shader_reference/shading_language.html#uniforms) mentions:

> It's important to understand that textures that are supplied as color require hints for proper sRGB->linear conversion (i.e. hint_albedo), as Godot's 3D engine renders in linear color space.

So change this line:

```
uniform sampler2D albedo;
```

To this:

```
uniform sampler2D albedo:hint_albedo;
```

And it should give you the expected result.